# Best player to stream WMV content - in 64 bits?

Tags: silverlight, 64-bit, jwplayer, wmv

I just realized that a client is using the JW WMV player to stream a .wmv broadcast. When I visit the page in Firefox it tells me I need to restart firefox in 32bit because the plugin is not available in 64 bits.

So I guess the JW WMV player is built on silverlight, which currently only supports 32 bit.

My question is this: Is there a better solution to embed a wmv stream on a webpage? Or is it OK just acceptable ask your viewers to restart their browser in 32 bit mode in order to view streaming content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed it.  There is no 64-bit version of the Silverlight plug-in. Why Microsoft has a 64-bit OS, but not a 64-bit version of their own plug-in, is a mystery.  If you are using a 64-bit version of Windows you will need to use the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer to view the video.  Both the 64-bit version of IE and the 32-bit version are included with the OS.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Microsoft%20Silverlight&v=Microsoft&uid=3&pf=0&pi=0&c=Communication%20%26%20Internet&sc=Web%20Browsers%20%26%20Plug-ins&os=32-bit